# Creating Pool of Ids in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, random, pool

I need to create a pool of ids for my project. If a user comes, I need to allocate them an id for a certain event. If they delete that event, I need to delete that id and put it back in my id pool.

Let's say A user named Sam comes and creates a certain event. I allocate him id `4343`. If he deletes that event, I need to delete that id and put it back in my id pool. I created the id pool in MongoDB.

My question: Consider my id pool ranges from `0-5000`. I have 4000 users. I am generating an id using `randint()` in Python, and I check with the id pool whether the id is used or not. If the id is not used, I will assign the id for the user. I am thinking of generating this id pool in an efficient way, because each time I generate one, I need to check with db list. It is not efficient in a longer run.

If I implement this, it has a lot of delay for assigning after 4000 users, because each time `randint()` generates the id and calls the db list and checks it, it takes more time, because if the given id ( example: 3000) already exists, it needs to generate again, and again if it exists it needs to generate another, etc.

Comment: Can you please provide the code for what you tried so far?
Also, do you really need to have a pool of IDs or each user having a unique ID is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Create a List which contains values from 0-5000.Choose a random use form the list and assign it to a use and remove it from that list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).